# js card validation without converting to string or array

Tags: javascript, credit-card, cs50

I'm trying to create a cs50 card validator with JavaScript. I'm having problems with the checksum counting. It should be `sum % 10 === 0 //true`.

```js
let cards = [378282246310005, 371449635398431,
        5555555555554444, 5105105105105100, 4012888888881881,
        4012888888881880, 1234567890, 361049635398431], result = '';

cards.forEach( card => {
    if (isCardValid(card)) {
        result += card + ' = ';
        checkBank(card);
    }
});

document.getElementById('task6').innerHTML = result;

function checkBank(card) {
    if ((card >= 340000000000000 && card < 350000000000000) || (card >= 370000000000000 && card < 380000000000000))
        result += ("AMEX\n");
    else if (card >= 5100000000000000 && card < 5600000000000000)
        result += ("MASTERCARD\n");
    else if ((card >= 4000000000000 && card < 5000000000000) || (card >= 4000000000000000 && card < 5000000000000000))
        result += ("VISA\n");
    else
        result += ("INVALID\n");
}

function isCardValid(digits) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        let cardNum = parseInt(digits[i]);

        if ((digits.length - i) % 2 === 0) {
            cardNum = cardNum * 2;

            if (cardNum > 9) {
                cardNum = cardNum - 9;
            }
        }

        sum += cardNum;
    }

    return sum % 10 === 0;
}
```

Here is some data to check validator work:

- 378282246310005 `//AMEX`
- 371449635398431 `//AMEX`
- 5555555555554444 `//MASTERCARD`
- 5105105105105100 `//MASTERCARD`
- 4012888888881881 `//VISA`
- 4012888888881880 `//INVALID`
- 1234567890 `//INVALID`
- 361049635398431 `//INVALID`

The main thing is, i can't use strings, arrays and any ready to use functions. Waiting for your help, thanks.

**UPD**
I solved the issue with an algorithm except for this card:

- 4012888888881880 `//INVALID`

My code thinks that this is a VISA card. Bank validation looks fine, so i don't know where to find the problem. Any suggestions where is problem?

**UPD2**
Final version

```js
let cards = [378282246310005, 371449635398431,
        5555555555554444, 5105105105105100, 4012888888881881,
        4012888888881880, 1234567890, 361049635398431], result = '';

cards.forEach( card => {
    if (isCardValid(card)) {
        result += card + ' = ';
        checkBank(card);
    } else {
        result += card + ' = INVALID Card\n'
    }
});

document.getElementById('task6').innerHTML = result;

function checkBank(card) {
    if ((card >= 340000000000000 && card < 350000000000000) || (card >= 370000000000000 && card < 380000000000000))
        result += ("AMEX\n");
    else if (card >= 5100000000000000 && card < 5600000000000000)
        result += ("MASTERCARD\n");
    else if ((card >= 4000000000000 && card < 5000000000000) || (card >= 4000000000000000 && card < 5000000000000000))
        result += ("VISA\n");
    else
        result += ("INVALID Bank\n");
}

function isCardValid(card) {
    let sum = 0, len, first = 0, second = 0;

    for (len=0; card; Math.floor(card /= 10), ++len) {
        let digit = Math.floor(card % 10);
        second = first;
        first = digit;

        if (len & 1) {
            digit += digit;
            if (digit > 9) {
                digit -= 9;
            }
        }
        sum += digit;
    }

    return sum % 10 === 0;
}
```

```html
<pre id="task6"></pre>
```

Comment: `378282246310005` for this input your sum is `67.6` how do you expect `sum%10 === 0` be true ?

Comment: @CodeManiac i think problem in my code, but can't understand where

Comment: "i can't use strings, arrays and any ready to use functions" Why? Is this an exercise or a test question?

Comment: @JordanRunning yes

Comment: Please take a look at [Open letter to students with homework problems](//meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166). Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is [just an assignment without showing any research of implementation effort](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/). Edit your question and show what you have tried to keep it from getting put on hold.

Comment: @JohnConde but i tried, you can see my code under the spoiler

Comment: It is  showing the result of the prior card (which is a valid VISA), because the `if (isCardValid(card))` is false, therefore `result` will not change.